# "Vor einer langen Zeit": why einer and not einen?

Tags: declension

In one lesson from the software Memrise, there is the sentence `Vor einer langen Zeit`.
(but there are not so many matches when I google it)

If ever the sentence is correct and common, I don't understand why it is not: `Vor einen langen Zeit`. Why does the declension becomes `einer`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The preposition *vor* is used with the Dativ in this case (no pun intended).

From the [Duden Online entry](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vor_bevor_aus_gegen_heraus):

> drückt aus, dass etwas dem genannten Zeitpunkt oder Vorgang [unmittelbar] vorausgeht; früher als; bevor das Genannte erreicht ist
>
> Grammatik
>   mit Dativ; zeitlich
>
> Beispiele
>   vor wenigen Augenblicken
>   vor Ablauf der Frist
>   das war schon vor Jahren, vor meiner Zeit
>   [...]

*Zeit* is a female noun and this is the correct declination:

1. die / eine Zeit
2. der / einer Zeit
3. der / **einer** Zeit
4. die / eine Zeit

If you're asking why the adjective is *langen* and not *langer*, it's because of the German [strong and weak declination](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Starke_Deklination_der_Adjektive). If an adjective is used *without* an article it will be strongly declined:

> vor langer Zeit

and with article, it will be *weakly* declined:

> vor einer langen Zeit

**A side note**

> Vor einer langen Zeit ...

is grammatically correct, but this version is commonly used

> Vor langer Zeit ...

Comment: OK, but then what I don't understand is why it is not "Vor einer langer Zeit"... I don't understand the mismatch between `ein` and `lang` declensions.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I updated my answer. See the Wikipedia article I linked for strong and weak declination.

Comment: Good explanation, but the most important comment for this particular phrase is the last two lines.

Answer (score 4):

**"Vor" is a space or time preposition**, and there is a very simple rule (that you might already know if you learned Latin at school) which applies to a lot of these prepositions :

- If there is a movement in the direction indicated, then use Akkusativ (it's a special accusative called directive i think) : "Ich gehe vor das Haus"   means you go to the back of the house.
- If there is no movement in the direction indicated, then use Dative (it's called locative) : "Ich gehe vor dem Haus" means you're already in the front of the house, just walking there in no precise direction and watching the sun.

The prepositions this rule **doesn't apply to** are all fixed-case prepositions or expressions like aus, zu, ausserhalb von (dative) or um, über (accusative) as well as some figurative expressions  (eg Geh vor dich hin = go in front of yourself = just go ahead)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

The indefinite article "`ein`" has to be declined in congruency with the noun "`Zeit`". To decline "`ein`" correctly, you need to determine:

1. the gender
2. the case

of the noun. The grammatical gender of "`Zeit`" is female. And this fact rules out "`einen`" as option; see [this overview](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=ein&features=(Manner%20Indef)(Cat%20Art)(Num%20SG)&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) regarding how to decline "`ein`". So, "`einen`" can't be correct in connection with "`Zeit`", independent of the case.

So, you finally have to select between "`eine`" and "`einer`". Here, you'll have to look at the case of the noun (see splattne's answer), so "`einer`" is correct.

To pick up your comment regarding "`lang`":

"`lang`" is quite difficult to handle: just compare the declination table for "`ein`" cited above to [that overview of the different forms](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=lang&features=(Cat%20A)&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) of "`lang`".

In this case, you need the first three tables for the "positive" (neither comparative, nor superlative) form of "`lang`". Here, we need the third table, because there's "`ein`", so it's a case of mixed inflection. The noun is singular female dative, so the correct version is "`einer langen`".

Comment: Are you shure that "einer" is a pronoun? I would say it is an undefined article ("unbestimmter Artikel"). Or can it be both?

Comment: You're right of course - in this case, "`ein`" is a indefinite article. There's also a pronoun "`einer`" ("`Einer von uns hat Recht...oder wir beide?`"), but in this case, it's the article. I've edited my answer to eliminate the mis-places pronoun and to provide a link to the correct declination table.

Comment: More on "`einer`" as pronoun at canoo: http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-einer3.html?MenuId=Word4264